# Visual feedback after executing mapping

Tags: key-bindings

I have the following mapping in my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
 map <F3> my0v$"+y`y
```

It works correctly, but I'd like some visual feedback or some other indication to show that I've pressed the key. Any suggestions?

Comment: No answer, but isn't that the same as `map <F3> "+yy`?

Comment: This will copy the line character-wise instead of linewise. However, it will also copy the newline so it feels more linewise. I agree that it would probably be easier to just do `yy`/`Y` or `:yank` and just accept to do a little cleanup on paste/put.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have options:

- Explicitly put an `:echo` at the end of your mapping. `map <key> foo:echo "done"<cr>`
- Use `'showcmd'` which will show partial commands. This will give you a slight clue that something happened for multi-key mappings/commands. (Not really helpful here)
- Use a plugin like [vim-highlightedyank](https://github.com/machakann/vim-highlightedyank) to quickly highlight the last yank

General rule of thumbs for [mappings](https://vimways.org/2018/for-mappings-and-a-tutorial/):

- Supply a mode for mappings. e.g. `nmap` for normal mode
- Use `*noremap` variants unless you want remapping to occur or using a `<Plug>` mapping

This means your mapping would look like:

```
nnoremap <F3> my0v$"+y`y
```

Some more thoughts:

- This is very similar to `"+yy`/`"+Y`, `:yank +`, or `V"+y`. There is another newline in the register, but that is easy to reason about.
- You may not want the ending newline at all, so use `g_` instead of `$`.
- This mutates the `y` mark. This could be surprising, consider using a `:yank` or `yy`/`Y`
- Could ["cast"](https://github.com/vim-scripts/UnconditionalPaste) put/paste or change the register type to accomplish the same effect. e.g. `nnoremap <f3> "+yy:call setreg('+', @+, 'v')<cr>`

Personally, I lean toward using [vim-highlightyank](https://github.com/machakann/vim-highlightedyank) and the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <f3> "+yy:call setreg('+', @+, 'v')<cr>
```